# nginx .php rewrite rules not work

Tags: php, nginx

hi i have a rewrite rules for http to https and remove .php extension
but this work fine for http to https but not work .php extension 
please check whats problem in this

```
http {

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  servername;
    return 301 https://sitename.com$request_uri;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        ### OTHER CONFIGS ###
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the server block for `https://sitename.com`?

Comment: i have change domain above sitename its example

Comment: I can see a server block with `listen 80` for `http` but where is the `listen 443 ssl` server block (for `https`)?

Comment: no let it . we face not issue https but face issue .php extension not work .

Answer (score 0):

The server block in your example is equivalent to this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  servername;
    return 301 https://sitename.com$request_uri;
}
```

Everything after the `return` statement is effectively ignored. The server block has a single purpose, which is to redirect everything from `http` to `https` **unmodified**.

If you need to redirect to `https` with a modified URL, you could use a `rewrite ... permanent` statement instead of the `return 301` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: thanks but i asked about .php extension remove those not work